# Pass all entry in function argument

Tags: python, tkinter

```
for x, z in enumerate(data):
           x_label = tk.Label(mod_window, text=z, width=10, anchor='e')
           x_label.place(x=5, y=ycoord_count)
           x_entry = tk.Entry(mod_window, width=25)
           x_entry.place(x=100, y=ycoord_count)
           x_entry.insert(0, f'{dati_user[0][x+1]}')
           y_coord_count += 40

modifica_button = tk.Button(mod_window, text='Modifica', width=7, relief='groove',
                                   command=lambda :self.test(x_entry))
```

i need to pass all entries into command function argument.
I know i can easily do it with a list of entries but i need to pass the entry value modified by the user.
I thought about creating a dictionary of entry with a var.trace('w', func_to_update_dict_value) but... is there a solution to pass all entries into the function argument?

right now, it only passes the last entry

Comment: What is the issue if a list of entries is used?

Comment: it pass my entry.insert(value) instead of the value modified by the user... i can solve it with a func to update the list/dict before button command but if there's something to pass all entries in an argument it would be amazing

Comment: I don't think using a list is an issue at all, as long as the list you build has the Entry objects in it. So don't use the `.get()` function  when building the list but put the `x_entry` objects in a list and use `.get()` in your `self.test` function.

Comment: I don't get what your issue is as passing a list of entries as an argument is actually what you said *"pass all entries in an argument"*.